# Using decorators for database access with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am constructing a model that does large parts of its calculations in a Postgresql database (for performance reasons). It looks somewhat like this:

```
def sql_func1(conn):
    # prepare some data, crunch some number, etc.
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("SOME SQL COMMAND")
    curs.commit()
    curs.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname='name', user='user', password='pass', host='localhost', port=1234)
    sql_func1(conn)
    sql_func2(conn)
    sql_func3(conn)
    connection.close()
```

The script uses around 30 individual functions like `sql_func1`. Obviously it is a little awkward to manage the connection and cursor in each function all the time. Thus I started using a decorator as described [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2010/10/22/passing-connections-functions-using-decorator/). Now I can simply wrap `sql_func1` with a decorator `@db_connect` and pass the connection from there. However, that means I am opening and closing the connection all the time, which is not good practice either. The [psycopg2 FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#best-practices) says:

> Creating a connection can be slow (think of SSL over TCP) so the best
>   practice is to create a single connection and keep it open as long as
>   required. It is also good practice to rollback or commit frequently
>   (even after a single SELECT statement) to make sure the backend is
>   never left “idle in transaction”. See also psycopg2.pool for
>   lightweight connection pooling.

Could you please give me some insights which would be an ideal practice im my case. Should I rather use a decorator that passes the `cursor` object instead of the `connection`? If so, please provide a code sample for the decorator. As I am rather new to programming, please let me also know in case you think my overall approach is wrong.

Comment: Did you move as much logic as possible to SQL reducing the round trips?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto The model needs to be modular. Therefore I use a series of smaller functions. Did I get your question right?

Answer (score 1):

What about storing the connection in a global variable without closing it in the `finally` block? Something like this (according to the example you linked):

```
cnn = None
def with_connection(f):

    def with_connection_(*args, **kwargs):
        global cnn
        if not cnn:
            cnn = psycopg.connect(DSN)
        try:
            rv = f(cnn, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            cnn.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            cnn.commit() # or maybe not        
        return rv

    return with_connection_
```

Comment: Maybe I am not getting it, but this basically what I did in my code sample, no? What would be the advantage? Also I think you should add `cnn.close()` to the `exception` in your answer.

Comment: Basically yes but you would make use of the decorator (which initializes the connection if not already established). You don't need to close the connection in the `except` block (unless you want to close the connection if a single query failed)

Comment: OK, thanks. I had the impression that one big advantage of using the decorator was that one makes sure that the connection is closed. And passing the `cursor` with a decorator is not a good idea in your opinion?